# Fullscreen Desktop Windows and Android Application with Flutter

Tags: flutter, fullscreen

I'm developing a desktop application with Flutter. I wanted the application to run in fullscreen mode. The solution kept me busy for a while. To save you from being busy, I'm sharing the examples. My solution will be used to run in fullscreen mode on Windows and Android applications.

**Code example for Android application fullscreen**

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

code HERE

return MaterialApp

```
SystemUiOverlayStyle systemUiOverlayStyle = const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.transparent,
        systemNavigationBarContrastEnforced: false,
        systemStatusBarContrastEnforced: false);

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(systemUiOverlayStyle);
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky,
        overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
```

## Code example for Windows application fullscreen

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

dependencies:
window_manager: ^0.3.7

Usage :
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

runApp(const MyApp());
code here

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized();
  windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) async {
    await windowManager.setFullScreen(true);
    await windowManager.show();
```

Developing Flutter Desktop Fullscreen Applications for Windows and Android